# Entity Framework Reverse.POCO.Generator error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

Working with a context generated with Entity Framework Reverse POCO Generator, I got this error, multiple times for multiple tables relations.

> System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException: 'One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>   [...] Because all of the properties in the Dependent Role are non-nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '1'.

What's the nature of this error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow the FK to be Nullable

You could following the steps below to create and association between the two entities:

Right-click an empty area of the design surface, point to Add New, and select Association….
Fill in the settings for the association(One to Many between UserInformation entity and  Tokens entity) in the Add Association dialog

Note: You can choose to not add navigation properties or foreign key properties to the entities at the ends of the association by clearing the Navigation Property **and **Add foreign key properties to the  Entity checkboxes. If you add only one navigation property, the association will be traversable in only one direction. If you add no navigation properties, you must choose to add foreign key properties in order to access entities at the ends of the association.

3. Click OK.

Following page provides information  and detailed steps about setting up relationships in your model using the EF Designer